# Scroll to down in div (in Firefox and IE!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="aaa">sdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdfsdfas fasdfa asdf </div>

#aaa {
height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

$("#aaa").scrollTop = $("#aaa").scrollHeight;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PfA7Q/2/

Is possible doing scroll to down in this DIV in Firefox and in IE?

Comment: Technically, that isn't a div its a textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a bit wrong, as `scrollTop` in jQuery is actually a function, not a property. And scrollHeight is a native javascript property, not related to jQuery. So you'll want to do something like this :

```
$('#aaa').scrollTop($("#aaa")[0].scrollHeight);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PfA7Q/14/

That being said, you should probably cache your div reference in a variable instead of getting it two times, like this :

```
var $aaa = $('#aaa');
$aaa.scrollTop($aaa[0].scrollHeight);
```

Comment: Note that if you want to scroll to the bottom, you could also just pass a ridiculously big number to the scrollTop function and it will work. Not that I recommand it, but just so you know.

Comment: When you use jQuery's `$` function, jQuery returns an Array of DOM elements. Doing $('#aaa').scrollHeight is actually the same as trying to read the scrollHeight property of the array, wich doesn't make sense. That's why you have to get the DOM element directly by using [0] (the first item of the array).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#aaa").attr({ scrollTop: $("#aaa").attr("scrollHeight") });
```

Replace `attr`s with `prop` for jQuery 1.6+.